# How to apply text fade in hover effect to image in a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a text fade in effect when hovering over images in a table. I've gotten it to work with the image on its own, but when I try to apply it to the table element it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I hover over the image. I feel like I am arranging something wrong. Is it not possible to do in a table?

Here's the code:

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 50px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

td {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Cat 1</th>
    <th>Cat 2</th>
    <th>Cat 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <div class="container">
      <td class="cat1"><img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2012/11/91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg" height="150px" width="150px"></td>
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Overlay Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <td class="cat2"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a096cce4b00d7644776a0b/562b9546e4b016f977a96bd7/562b975fe4b01024eb5d7267/1445697377179/Shake_11_Lil+Bub.jpg?format=1500w" height="150px" width="150px"></td>
    <td class="cat3"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg" height="150px" width="150px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/megmun/f7esrn0t/

Comment: Just to clarify; you want to hover over the cat images and for each hover you want the `.text` element to fade in?

Comment: The structure of a table must be `<tr> <td> CONTENT </td> </tr>`. Your `container` div is directly inside of a `<tr>` element, which is invalid.  The browser will attempt to fix this by moving the container *outside* of the table instead, which I'm assuming is breaking your intended functionality. In the future, a simple `Right Click > Inspect Element...` can reveal issues like this quite easily.

Comment: To add on to my comment above, you'll likely need a container/overlay in *each* `<td>` if you're trying to do this with CSS only. Otherwise you can use one single overlay and position it using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big problem was placing divs around TD elements.
And css was almost ok but here goes a tip:

**Position: absolute** elements will be constrained within other position **non static** elements (relative, other absolute and fixed) so for your TD contain the absolute overlay it must be **relative**.

```css
.grid {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 50px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.grid td {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.grid td:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid">
  <tr>
    <th>Cat 1</th>
    <th>Cat 2</th>
    <th>Cat 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>

      <img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2012/11/91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg" height="150px" width="150px" />

      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Overlay Text</div>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a096cce4b00d7644776a0b/562b9546e4b016f977a96bd7/562b975fe4b01024eb5d7267/1445697377179/Shake_11_Lil+Bub.jpg?format=1500w" height="150px" width="150px" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg" height="150px" width="150px" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit:

Forgot to mention: You must also take care of vendor specific properties such as transition and transform.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the mess...Total beginner here. I really appreciate it.

Comment: oh np! Thats what the community is for! best regards!

Comment: Oh! BTW, check the answer as "Correct" if that is the case, and a thumbs up! best!